# Reorder the options in a select box with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a select box that dynamically shows a list of shipping options and prices. I want them to be in order from lowest to highest price.

Here's example html.

```
<select name="ShippingMethod">
  <option value="ups:1">UPS Next Day Air ($30.08)</option>
  <option value="ups:4">UPS 2nd Day Air ($14.77)</option>
  <option value="ups:6">UPS 3 Day Select ($10.93)</option>
  <option value="ups:7">UPS Ground ($8.00)</option>
  <option value="flatzonc:Pick up in store">Pick up in store ($0.00)</option>
  <option value="mvusps:PRIORITY">U.S.P.S. Priority Mail&reg; ($7.45)</option>
</select>
```

I know how to put the values into an array with this:

```
shippingOptions = [];
$('select[name=ShippingMethod] option').each(function() {
    myList.push($(this).html())
});
```

but thats as far as I got. I don't know how to use that to sort them and reinsert them in order. I'm new to javascript so I appriciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to do some string manipulation to parse out the contents of the parens and sort that.

Comment: On what basis do you want to sort..? value?

Comment: Can't you do that on the server end? It's probably more appropriate do do it there.

Comment: Would you post the code that populates the list originally? It may be easier to sort the list originally than to re-sort it. Do you ever have the price as a discrete value?

Comment: I can't do it on the server side. The web site is a MIVA merchant store and I don't have access to any of their scripting.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/hPZ3F/17

```
// get all options
var shippingOptions = $('select[name=ShippingMethod] option');

// initialize sort
shippingOptions.sort(function(a,b) {
    // define regex that pulls contents of parens
    var patt = /\((.*)\)/;

    // for each element in sort, find the price and remove the dollar sign
    a.price = a.text.match(patt)[1].replace('\$', '');
    b.price = b.text.match(patt)[1].replace('\$', '');

    return a.price - b.price;
});

// update the select with the new option order
$('select[name=ShippingMethod]').append(shippingOptions);

// select the first option
$(shippingOptions[0]).attr("selected", "");
```

Comment: you actually don't need the empty() either - but +1

Comment: Wow thanks! It worked perfect. The only issue is I have 2 select boxes on that page. Thats why I used "select[name=ShippingMethod]" instead of just "select" for the jQuery selector. Thanks. Could you walk me through how that works?

Comment: Updated. You just need to reference the [name] attribute twice.

Comment: i have one more problem. For some reason the option with the highest price is selected by default. It doesn't have the "selected" attribute, but it's allways selected by default. I need to add the "selected attribute" to the first object in the array. How can I tell jQuery to select it. This doesn't work - $(shippingOptions[0]).attr("selected");

Comment: You don't ask for much, do you? :D  Answer updated. You were close.

Comment: ahh! why didn't I figure that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to extract the $ amount of each option, then sort those and replace the existing dropdown, here is the complete code:

http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/L8qgX/

```
// Get the price in the option
    var getPrice = function (str) {
        var price = 0;
        var result = str.match(/[0-9]+(.)[0-9]{2}/);    //regex matches >1 digit followed by . decimal, followed by 2 digits
        if (result.length > 0) {
            price = parseFloat(result[0]);
        }
        return price;
    };

// Sort the prices
    var sortPrices = function (priceList) {
        priceList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.price > b.price; // > is sort ascending order
        });
        return priceList;
    };

var prices = [];
// Get the option's label, value, price
    $('select[name=ShippingMethod] option').each(function () {
        var option = $(this);
        var price = getPrice(option.text());
        prices.push({
            label: option.html(),
            value: option.val(),
            price: price
        });
    });

var shippingOptions = sortPrices(prices);

// create output HTML
var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i < shippingOptions.length; i++) {
    output += '<option value="' + shippingOptions[i].value + '">' + shippingOptions[i].label + '</option>';
}

// replace <select> with sorted options
$('select[name="ShippingMethod"]').html(output);
```

You can learn more about using:

- `match()` with regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
- `sort()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2):

Meh, already answered but I had this written up so I'll post anyway, It's pretty much a mix of all the rest of these, lol.. Fancy that

```
$('select[name=ShippingMethod]').
    html($('select[name=ShippingMethod] option').
         clone().sort(function (a, b) {
            a = a.innerHTML, b = b.innerHTML;
            return parseFloat(
                    a.substr(a.indexOf('$') + 1)
                ) >= parseFloat(
                    b.substr(b.indexOf('$') + 1)
                );
        })
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zbzK/

Edit: After reviewing the comments, this is a more efficient but more verbose answer:

```
var selectOpts = $('select[name="ShippingMethod"] option');
var len = selectOpts.length;
var options = new Array(len), out = "", i;
selectOpts.each(function (index) {
    var self = $(this);
    var txt = self.text();
    options.push({
        'html': '<option value="' + self.val() + '">' + txt + '</option>',
        'price': parseFloat(txt.substr(txt.indexOf('$') + 1))
    });
    // Return if not last item
    if (index !== len - 1) {
        return;
    }
    // Sort options and set 'out'
    options.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.price > b.price;
    });
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        out += options[i].html;
    };
}).parent('select').html(out);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QnHFH/

Comment: I like how short it is :) But I'm afraid beginner JavaScript developers would have a hard time following what it's doing. Either way, kudos~

Comment: Also want to point out your custom `.sort()` function is likely to be the performance bottle neck for large sets because it's doing so much in there.

Comment: Beginners may not know functional programming, and the best way to do this is a functional problem. The only way to get better is to practice and figure out how things work. If they know jQuery 'html' or 'clone' they should get the gist of it, the sort() function- which I think all of the results used, is the hard part for beginners, I think.

Comment: @sweetamylase, no matter what you do here, you need to get the innerHTML and parse a float in order to compare. I don't think "substr" is any slower than regex alternatives, but I could be wrong. What can I do to optimize this? I tried without cloning but the DOM preserves the order of the elements... Um, yeah, I don't see the "so much" you are talking about, it all seems necessary to me at first glance, I must be missing something.

Comment: Spencer, please explain your assertion regarding functional problems as the best way here. I'm listening.

Comment: @isherwood The sort function in JavaScript is functional; You pass a function, and that function takes two arguments to compare, returns either 1 or -1, and with that simple functional specification and built-in nature, it is the best way to approach this "sorting" problem in JavaScript. If you know of a different/better way, please do tell.

Comment: @SpencerLockhart Well just comparing the `.sort()` function which executes 15 times, in this example.  Doing `a.price > b.price` is definitely faster than accessing the DOM eg.`a.innerHTML` and `b.innerHTML`. That's (15*2) vs 6 (# of <option>) DOM accesses.

Comment: @sweetamylase, thank-you for that explanation. After looking at your response I see what you mean. I think you have the right idea with your algorithm, this is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/QnHFH/

Comment: @SpencerLockhart Cools. Performance isn't what people normally think of. I've watched a few of Nicholas Zakas' youtube vidoes and he made it apparent that accessing the DOM is an expensive operation. Here's one: http://youtu.be/_fUGWFGUrUw

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. Here Sorting is done on value.. You can use `.text` to sort based on text

```
$("select").html($("select option").sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1  ;
}));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zHqxj/)

Sort on text:  [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/zHqxj/3/)

```
 return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1 ;
```

Sort on values indside braces in text : **[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/zHqxj/5/)**

```
$("select").html($("select option").sort(function (a, b) {
    var a1 =  parseFloat(a.text.match(/\(.*?([\d.]+).*?\)/)[1].replace("$",""));
    var b1 =  parseFloat(b.text.match(/\(.*?([\d.]+).*?\)/)[1].replace("$",""));
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a1 < b1 ? -1 : 1
}));
```

Comment: Won't this end up sorting alpha?